# Sample values from a grid by points in RQGIS

Tags: grids-graticules, sample, rqgis

I need to sample values from a grid by points. In RSGA, there is a function called "pick.from.saga.grid" to sample raster data set using points. Is there something similar in RQGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the source code of `pick.from.saga.grid`, you will realize that it is an independent R function. That means the function does not use SAGA in the background but instead uses an interpolation algorithm in R (nearest neighbour, ordinary kriging) to extract grid values to points.

So far, RQGIS only provides an interface to QGIS without offering additional R-specific geospatial processing capabilities. If needed, this could change in the future. However, since the `pick.from.saga.grid`-function already exists, I rather would not duplicate it in RQGIS.